# Check simplexml_load_file file to avoid warnings

Tags: php

When calling an external API with simplexml_load_file a server timeout or similar will generate warnings. Using file_exists on e.g. http://www.api.com?query=xyz does not work. Is there any built in function or appropriate solution for a  simple check before performing the simplexml_load_file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents), which you can check if it was successful based on its return values (false on failure, data on success). You can also use `@` like so to suppress any warnings:

```
if( $data = @file_get_contents( $filename)) ...
```

Finally, use [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) instead of simplexml_load_file using the data that `file_get_contents` returned to create your SimpleXMLElement object.